# Firebase callable function doesn't return JSON response in Android SDK

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase callable function in Android is not returning a JSON response, instead it's returning `Hashmap<String, Object>`, which can't be converted to JSONObject.

How to get the JSON object, which is returned in cloud function?

e.g. I'm returning this JSON in the cloud function and I need this JSON in android callable function.

```
return ({
    status: 'failed',
    message: 'No error (00)',
    data: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're observing is simply the way callables work.  On Android, you're going to see a HashMap that aligns with the object that was returned from the callable function.  It's up to you to convert that HashMap to something else, if that's what you need.  The client SDK won't do it for you.  You can expect that the keys and values of the map match the properties and values of the returned object.  Simply logging the HashMap using its toString method will reveal this.

Comment: Why it's not returning JSONObject, as the callable functions always return JSON? My business logic is using JSON and it's complicated to convert Hashmap to JSON.

Comment: That's just not the way it works.  If you want a JSONObject, you'll have to convert the map yourself.  People largely don't use JSONObject any more - it's an old API and has bugs depending on the version of Android.  I suggest avoiding it.  It doesn't really offer anything special.  If you want to make a suggestion for the callable SDK, you should do that on GitHub, but I don't think they're going to make this sort of change. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk